# Error about package is not visible for JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am trying to convert my JavaFX application in to a Maven JavaFX program so I can export the project to an single executable.

But the following imports show a "package [name] is not visible" error.

```java
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
```

I assume that it has something to do with adding dependancy's in my pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>RnD_project_maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.rnd_project_maven.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But I have no idea how to solve this. I want to stress that I just started with Java and JavaFX. I just want to be able to share my simple application without the users having to use the command line to start my program.
If someone can explain to me what i am doing wrong or what i need to do that would be highly appreciated.

I am using NetBeans IDE 11.3 and Java 13 with javafx-sdk-11.0.2.

Comment: Probably a "requires" declaration in your project's module-info.java is missing.